# which is the best django study book

Tags: django

There u a lot of book teaching django, I just don't know which one is the best, so can anybody give me an answer

Comment: http://www.djangobook.com/ is THE BEST book. Hands down. I'm was a PHP programmer. I never wanted to learn django. But after few years, here I am searching for good book on django. I just wanted to give it a try. I watched some screencasts on show me do and other video tutorials on youtube. I started hated django. It looked too complex to me. I didn't understand why people where doing this and that while writing django apps. Finally yesterday I turned to djangobook.com as my last resort. I finished 5 chapters. Now, I LOVE django. Its awesome. The book is awesome!

Answer (score 12):

I would recommend [Practical Django Projects](http://books.google.com/books?id=xX5nkG8v7m0C) by James Bennett, it's really clear and practical.

Comment: really thank u. I've already downloaded this book and I think it will e helpful

Answer (score 7):

*Best* is subjective and what books do you already know?
I would not buy a printed book. Information is changing too fast.

I find the official [Django documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/) pretty useful, then there is the [Django book](http://www.djangobook.com/) and the [Django questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django) here on SO are useful too of course.
Also [this blog](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/categories/django/) (from one of the Django authors? I am not sure) gives some nice tipps and tricks.

Comment: The blog you mentioned is by James Bennett described http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/internals/committers/#specialists on as "Django’s release manager", he works on Ellington, the CMS from which Django was extracted.

Comment: Django Book is really useful. They use the examples from the docs, but give more explanation. This way you can figure out what's going on, and then reference the same examples in the docs for more advanced functionality

Comment: thanks both of you :) I'm just reading the book right now by your advice.

Answer (score 2):

I have found [The Definitive Guide to Django Web Development Done Right, 2nd edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143021936X) to be good.

Answer (score 1):

The online [official django tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) and documentation is quite good.

Comment: yes it is, but it's just not so convient, so i want some offline ones

Answer (score 1):

Good book for start creating practical Django application:"[Beginning Django Ecommerce](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430225351)"