# Adding community elements to a website with django

Tags: python, django, web, messaging, django-socialauth

I was wondering the best source of information regarding community elements with Django. I have finished some great Django books, and tutorials, but I have not been able to find a website or tutorial which covers what I am looking for.

I want to add a private user - user messaging system,
And some sort of rating system.
Also information about "Adding friends" and other this like this. But that might be beyond my scope of knowledge.

Also any advice about the best django tutorials, books, or screen casts would be awesome. I'm not a beginner, but I still need to learn a lot.

Thanks for any responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any place where you can find everything for building a social/community website, but:

[Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/) has tons of great apps for social networking (ratings, polls, user profiles, friend relationships, comments, notifications, activity streams), account management, openid, and more. Should get you about 90% of the way there.

As for learning and not readymade apps, you should study a few open-source social networks built on Django, etc.

You could also find websites on DjangoSites.com that are both, [on community building](http://www.djangosites.org/tag/community-building/) and [with source](http://www.djangosites.org/with-source/) and study their source codes.

There's a lot of good stuff at http://www.packtpub.com/article/building-friend-networks-with-django-1.0 even though it uses an older version.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have suggestions for a great django book? It doesn't have to be about social/community, just well written book with example code?

Comment: My favorite is the [Django documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com)! If you've already read a few Django books and articles, I think the best way for you to learn is to start coding! You'll learn much more doing that, as compared to reading books. When you come across problems, a great resource is [right here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django). You can also find a lot of code to learn form at the [Django Cookbook](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/CookBook). If you *have to* read a book, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370443/which-is-the-best-django-study-book

Answer (score 1):

Try [django-userena](http://www.django-userena.org/) for pm and invitations